# how can I run tests using different capybara drivers on different platforms in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a project that we've been developing thus far entirely on PCs and then deploying on linux.  We've developed our tests using `capybara` and `capybara-webkit` for javascript.

Turns out, as we try to run things on the mac with mountain lion, that `capybara-webkit` is broken (I get all kinds of pipe errors, 246 failures out of 1606 tests, 46 when switching to `webkit_debug`).  Judging from their web page and the number of times that error is reported, these kinds of failures just happen.  So, I'd like to run our rails tests on windows via `capybara` and `capybara-webkit`, but use something like selenium or some other comparable test driver (ie, so that the spec files and locations don't have to change).  How can I do this?  I'm familiar with C defines, would something like that in the gem files and spec_helper.rb files be sufficient?

Comment: So, you want to run another driver on the mac? It's bit unclear to me what you are asking for. [poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) is a phanthomJS driver for capybara that might work.

Comment: OK, not sure what the downvotes are for, but hey.  Also, @AndreasLyngstad I ended up using poltergeist on the mac side, since it actually works, but I still have different test drivers.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you do something along the lines of

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mac/
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :firefox
else
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
end
```

in spec/support/env.rb?

I don't have a mac, so I'm not sure what the value of `RUBY_PLATFORM` should be, but by running puts `RUBY_PLATFORM` in `irb`, I'm sure you can figure out an appropriate value.